# Two join or not -querying 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**Prodline**

Prodline_nbr

Prodline_name

prodline_color_code

prodline_discount

**product**

prod_nbr

prod_name

prod_price

prod_cost

i want to list name for each product, sale price, product line name, and color code for products whose price is no more than $200 and sort them descending order by sale price.

Here is my code

```
select PRODLINE_NAME,PRODLINE_COLOR_CODE,PROD_NAME, PROD_PRICE
from prodline, product
where PRODLINE_NBR in (select PRODLINE_NBR from prodline) 
and prod_price<=200 
order by PROD_PRICE desc;
```

Is this not correct? I've been told there is a better way by using some sorta join?

second attempt

```
select PRODLINE_NAME,PRODLINE_COLOR_CODE,PROD_NAME, PROD_PRICE
from prodline, product
where PRODLINE_NBR = PROD_NBR
and prod_price<=200 
order by PROD_PRICE desc;
```

Could anyone comment please?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't explain the relation between these tables.  Is prodline_nbr the same as prod_nbr?  The naming makes it sound like one represents categories of products and another represents the products themselves.  It seems like you need a prodline_nbr column in your products table; otherwise, how do you plan to match up the tables?

Comment: second attempt is better. You are "joining" the tables when you specify that PRODLINE_NBR = PROD_NBR. This forces the two tables to match up / join on that variable. If PRODLINE_NAME is supposed to be equal to PROD_NAME (this depends on your data), you would also join on them `AND PRODLINE_NAME = PROD_NAME`

Comment: Thanks Ed/Roberto - Apologies, yes prodline_Nbr = prod_Nbr, but prodline_name =/ prod_name. I'm sensing the second code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct. The first one is wrong, because it just multiply two tables, i guess this is not enough to achieve your goal.
Comparing your two scripts, the only difference is a condition in the where clause:

the first uses `PRODLINE_NBR in (select PRODLINE_NBR from prodline)`, which makes little sense, since PRODLINE_NBR is a field of prodline, of course every PRODLINE_NBR should in it. With this condition or not makes nothing different.

the second uses `PRODLINE_NBR = PROD_NBR`, which is a typical method to join two tables from multiplying them. If you want to connect o two tables through an equation among two fields, you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Second style is the best! There are many ways to produce same outputs. but efficiency matters.

this links are good to learn about HOW JOIN and INDEX work.

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/glossary.html#glos_selectivity
- http://www.keithjbrown.co.uk/vworks/mysql/mysql_p5.php